# Why is the default umask for root 022 in RHEL 7

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux

I noticed that root on our machines by default creates world-readable files, which I find unacceptable on servers with many users. My question is a simple one, but I can't seem to understand the logic behind Red Hat's decision to set the default value of umask for root (more precisely all UIDs < 200) to 022. Anyone who can answer this? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A possible answer is logs. Going root just to read logs would be a pain. I of crouse assume that RHEL main usage is servers where the few human users just log in for administration.

Comment: that does make sense. I'd be interested in other opinions/facts that I'm apparently missing